# respond_to? doesn't check singleton class

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to define a method on an instance, and then get `respond_to?` to return `true`.  Why doesn't this work?

```
user = User.new
user.define_singleton_method(:email) do
  "some email"
end

# This works
user.email #=> "some email"

# I would have expected this to return true
user.respond_to?(:email) #=> false
```

Is there any way I get a method defined on a single instance and have it respond correctly to `respond_to?`

**Update:** It turned out to be a Ruby on Rails issue. RoR provides a different responds_to? for Active Record models.

Comment: Can't reproduce. What ruby is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working fine for me with Ruby 2.3.7

```
class User
end

user = User.new

user.define_singleton_method(:email) do
  "some email"
end

# This works
puts user.email #=> "some email"

#This works too
puts user.respond_to?(:email) #=> true
```

Comment: Same with 2.5.3

Comment: Ah. I see the issue now.  Ruby on Rails provides a different respond_to?.  Thanks for verifying.

Answer (score 1):

Method is defined and exist on public methods list.
https://repl.it/repls/UnluckySpiffyPaint